# Is there a Vizard function to get virtual coordinates from a wand/hand tracker?

Tags: python, vizard

Trying to get virtual coordinates from my wand in Vizard 7. Using the MainView.getPosition function, I was able to get the virtual coordinates of the head tracker. Is there a function that can similarly show me the virtual world coordinates of my wand/hand tracker?

Using .getNode3d I was able to get the real world coordinates of my wand, but if I use the joystick to move around it does not update to show my coordinates in-world.